# Copied rails app but now devise is not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I copied an entire Rails app by doing this:

```
$ cp your-old-app your-new-app
```

and then creating a new database for it by doing this:

```
rake db:create db:migrate
```

Everything is working fine. Now I wanted to test my copied app and created a new user. Unfortunately this does not work. I am using the devise gem.

The error I get when trying to register a new test user is:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-11-12 19:07:42 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jrmiVvIOB+m2a0WCQWhL4LSpdfw2x9hxP6yhJOC6HVyjXOpTTrxWeF37sTtG/dYaeK1DBr/425svb2zEcO5mhQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"lkbkj23@test.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "lkbkj23@test.de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

In the thread that explained how to copy a Rails app, I read something about the need to create a new secret_token variable. This is the only idea I have what I could have been missing. But I do not know if this is the error and I do not know where and how to set up a new secret_token variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In root of your new project run:

```
rake secret
```

Now copy the output of this to your clipboard.  Then in config/initializer/devise.rb you need this line:

```
config.secret_key = "#{ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']}"
```

You'll need a way to load environment variables in your local development environment.  You can either use [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and then you'll have a file in root of project called `.env` and you'll add the key you generated with the rake command.  Or you might want to checkout [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) which appears to have not been updated/maintained recently. In your .env file add a line:

```
DEVISE_SECRET_KEY=<paste key here>
```

Make sure before making these changes, if you're using git version control to add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file.  This will insure you don't accidentally commit your key to your repo.